# how can i open a excel inside a web browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to open a excel in web browser when click a button.how to do that in asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control and launch software on the client (browser) computer - why? Security.

If this was possible, hackers would have taken over all computers long ago...

Can you please explain *exactly* what you are trying to do? Instead of asking how to open excel from the browser, if you explain what you need to accomplish, perhaps we can come up with a better idea.

Comment: k fine.actually i have tool when a user clicks on the button the excel sheet will open in a new window in order to make the user to stick into only one window i asked that.can u tell me is their any way i can make the user feel easy

Comment: @user628347 - So, you want an excel file that you are hosting to open up in excel?

Comment: i am able to create a new excel file and open as well,but i wanted it to open in the same window i mean browser where he his working if i couldn't do that then tell me any other way so that it makes easy for the user

Comment: @user628347 - Browsers can't display excel files. Excel does that. You can't embed excel inside a browser other than IE. I don't know how much easier than what you describe you want things to be.

Comment: @Oded This *is* possible: why? Security settings and IE ;-) Some enterprise-y (read: Microsoft SharePoint and related) tooling takes heavy advantage of this -- not that I recommend this route. Embedding is possible via ActiveX and OLE (and perhaps other ... so much dead-but-remaining technology over the years).

Comment: see i am designing excel import and export tool.for that when a user clicks on the particular table which i will be showing in the UI their will be a excel file opening but the user as to switch over from the browser and go to that excel file and fill it.i wanted the solution so that the user doesn't  go in search of the excel inspite of that i will only pop up or show the excel in web browser

Comment: @pst - IE only, not cross browser.

Comment: @user628347 - Do you have control over the browser being used?

Comment: @user628347 - Can't be done. IE has the facilities (which is how it can work for SharePoint), but not other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Google Docs Viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer) for opening a wide variety of files in the browser.

Example:

```
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fyoursite.com%2Fyourexcelsheet.xlsx
```

Comment: but one doubt i cant use a application right.should i need any copyright or something.because it a part of the project so

Comment: Yes, it's true. You have to read http://docs.google.com/viewer/TOS?hl=en carefully before usage so that the terms don't violate your company terms.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to give the url of the excel in the server

```
<a href ="... .xls"> Excel </a>
```

Only you can open a excel in `server` you can do.not in `Client`

Answer (score 0):

You can open and control and excel file on the server side with .net, then you can write an html/javascript frontend (or silverlight) for the actions. But you cannot open the ms excel itself as a dom object etc.

Look into the excel object model for .net.