# How secure is it to open word or excel files in web browser in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, ms-office, binaryfiles

I'm building a Document Management system in an asp.net 4.0 web application. The requirement is to open Office Documents in the web browser. The documents are stored in SQL server 2008 database in binary format.

Is it secure to open these files in the browser? If yes, then how to show/edit these files in a Web browser?

Comment: What kind of security you are talking about??

Comment: The system is to share confidential files between users. I wanted to know if are there greater chances of the system being susceptible to hacking if the files are opened in the browser. Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114751/how-can-i-open-a-excel-inside-a-web-browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebDAV protocol to achieve this. It is an extension on the Http protocol and supported in IIS. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV . Please refer to [the WebDAV project at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdav/) for further details. It is a decent library for serving WebDAV content.

For dealing with the Binary (I presume in SQL blob) content, you'll have to write the content to a file and then serve it over WebDAV.