# Not possible to open excel documents after open a document in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel, webbrowser-control

I am developing a windows application to merge two excel files and then view the result in webBrowser control.

I have done this but i am not able to open other Excel files after open the merged excel file in the       webBroser control.

```
 webBrowser1.Navigate(filename+".xlsx");
```

I followed the above statement to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel in Web Browser control locks the other workbooks sharing the same instance of EXCEL.exe. so it is not possible to open same instance at same time. but you will work on different instances or create new instance. it work fine...

Comment: Can you please explain me with a piece of code to solve this or give me useful links.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to insert an hyperlink.

Check this link:

[how can i open a excel inside a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114751/how-can-i-open-a-excel-inside-a-web-browser)